# Issue with having a div centered in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

Before someone labels this as a duplicate, I have searched on here and not finding a solution that quite fits what I need to do.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/sscuL/)

Here is the code for the html..

```
<div class="top-background"></div>
<div class="center-content"></div>
<div class="bottom-background"></div>
```

and here is the CSS stylesheet...

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
.top-background {
background-color:black;
width:100%;
height:50%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.bottom-background {
background-color:white;
width:100%;
height:50%;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
.center-content {
background-color:yellow; 
width:250px; 
height:120px;
margin: auto;
position:relative;
}
```

I can move the center-content div towards center by using top:300px. But that won't be any good because of depending on screen size.

The center-content div will have a graphic in it (it will not be a yellow background as shown), the graphic is reversed in the colors I have. I could have probably done this in the body along with text-align center, but then everything I put in will align center (and that's not going to be pretty) and used a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this:

```
.center-content {
background-color:yellow; 
width:250px; 
height:120px;
margin: auto;
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -60px; /* half of the height */
margin-left: -125px; /* half of the width */
}
```

Comment: this centers it, but when I run it, the bottom half of the center-content div disappears where its white but shows up on the black part

Comment: I figured out why the yellow was disappearing on the white part, it was because I had the center-content sandwiched between the top and bottom-background

Answer (score 2):

For doing this  assing some css properties to the class `center-content` is enough..

```
.center-content {
background-color:yellow; 
width:250px; 
height:120px;
margin: auto;
position:relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -125px;
}
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/sscuL/